# Flash Security Policy: Is there a work around to allow the blocked IP 127.0.0.2?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, azure

For local development of a Flash game we need to run servers at 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.0.2. Adobe security policy doesn't have a problem with 127.0.0.1 but it explicitly blocks 127.0.0.2.

We use Windows Azure as our hosting platform and recent changes to the Windows Azure Compute Emulator are requiring us to use both of these IP addresses.

Does anyone know a work-around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the [Flash Player Global Security Settings Panel](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html) may allow you to resolve this.

Add your the local directory where the SWF's are served from (or add 127.0.0.2?) to the box labeled "always trust files in these locations".

Comment: So it turns out this wasn't a problem at all. There was a bug in the server causing failed communication between the server running on 127.0.0.2.

Comment: Sorry to bump an old post.. not much info on this now-a-days..

I am using an RPi.

Running on localhost/127.0.01

I can NOT seem to get my Flash XMLSocket() connection to work.. each time is says 'not connected' on my screen.

var rpi_usb0_Listener = new XMLSocket();

rpi_usb0_Listener.connect('localhost', 7777);
rpi_usb0_Listener.onConnect = function(result){
 if(result){
  //connected
  state_txt.text = "connected";
 }else{
  //not connected
  state_txt.text = "not connected";
 }

}


How did you get the security policy working in your Flash app on localhost?